# Hide a div's span when a different div contains specific text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the 3 divs below:

```
<div class="price"><span>FREE</span> <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div></div><br/>

<div class="price"><span>$250 USD</span> <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div></div><br/>

<div class="price"><span>$800 USD</span> <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div></div>
```

What i want to do is to hide the `"transaction-type"` div every time the span contains the word `"free"`.

I already know that i can use jquery like that to target and hide the specific span:

```
if ($('.price>span').text().indexOf('FREE') >= 0) {
$('.transaction-type').hide();
}
```

My problem is that my code hide also all other spans that contain different content than `"FREE"` word.

You can check my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/1maewneu/5/)

Comment: Cycle the `span`s and look for your current `span`'s sibling with `$(this).siblings('.transaction-type')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop over the elements and use `$(this)` to refer to the one being looped over. Then use:

```
$('.price>span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf('FREE') >= 0) $(this).next('.transaction-type').hide();
})
```

```js
$('.price>span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf('FREE') >= 0) $(this).next('.transaction-type').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price"><span>FREE</span>
  <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div>
</div>
<br/>

<div class="price"><span>$250 USD</span>
  <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div>
</div>
<br/>

<div class="price"><span>$800 USD</span>
  <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @j08691. It worked fine. I feel so excited everytime i learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to target specific instances

```js
$('.price>span:contains("FREE")').siblings('.transaction-type').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price"><span>FREE</span> <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div></div><br/>

<div class="price"><span>$250 USD</span> <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div></div><br/>

<div class="price"><span>$800 USD</span> <div class="transaction-type">FOR SELL</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check case sensitive with pattern

```
   $('.price > span').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text()==="FREE"){
    $(this).next().hide();
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `contains` you will still have a jQuery object at the end, with which you can simply hide it with `hide()`:

```
$('.price>span:contains("FREE")').hide()
```